# Excel VBA - Extremely slow cell coloring

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a series of .csv files that I'm importing, which contain color information I need to apply to the imported data.  The color column is colon-delimited, and the data is pipe-delimited:

```
:::::65535::|ADAM 14-22TGH|CHERRY|twu|Diesel Fuel (RIG)|Fuel||
::::14994616:::|MARCO 41-12G|CRYSTAL|HVA|Diesel Fuel (RIG)|Rig Fuel|gal us|
:::65535:65535:65535:65535:|MARCO 41-12G|CRYSTAL|||||
```

The excel sheet contains defined colors for various data states (missing data, wrong data, too high, too low, etc.), so I loop through the imported data building a cell union, which I eventually apply colorization to:

```
Dim ds As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long  
Dim iUsedCol As Long, iUsedRow As Long, clrRequired As Long, color as Long
Dim rngRequired As Range

Dim colorMap As Variant
Dim colors() As String
clrRequired = CLng(GetSetting("Failed Required Field Check"))

' Get the values of the color column
iusedRow = ds.UsedRange.Rows.Count
colorMap = Range(ds.Cells(1, 1), Cells(iUsedRow, 1)).Value

' Delete the color map column
ds.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete

' Skip the first two rows
For i = 3 To iusedRow
    colors = Split(colorMap(i, 1), ":")

    ' Offset by one column since we're deleting column 1 after
    For j = 2 To UBound(colors) + 1
        If colors(j - 1) = "" Then
        Else
            color = CLng(colors(j - 1))

            ' Required
            If color = clrRequired Then
                If rngRequired Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngRequired = ds.Cells(i, j)
                Else
                    Set rngRequired = Application.Union(rngRequired, ds.Cells(i, j))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

' Set the colors
If Not rngRequired Is Nothing Then
    rngRequired.Interior.color = clrRequired
End If
```

For simplicity I removed the three other identical checks for the other colors, but this is the pattern.  Depending on the data this can be 50 rows or 12000 rows, with varying columns based on what is being checked.  I have a report that takes over 20 minutes to run, and when I remove this coloring code it finishes in about 10 seconds.

Additionally here is what I am disabling while running the code:

- Calculations
- CancelKey
- PrintCommunication
- ScreenUpdating
- Events
- StatusBar
- Alerts

Comment: How many rows/cells in the 20-minute example? If you comment out just the last 3 lines is it significantly faster ?

Comment: @TimWilliams good question.  Just checked and it appears to be just as slow, which points to the union operation likely taking the longest.  Originally I had it coloring one cell at a time, which was even slower.

Comment: @TimWilliams the report I'm currently testing is just over 33,000 lines spread out over 12 csv files.  Most are small, one is 30k all by itself.

Comment: Is iusedRow just 33,000, or is it thinking it is about 1,000,000?  (i.e. does Excel think your UsedRange goes to the end of the worksheet?)

Comment: @YowE3K great point, let me check.  I'd expect if that were the case I'd see it perform just as slow regardless of data, but its worth taking a look at.

Comment: I'm assuming that the If without an EndIf (just inside the For j loop) is just a typo when you were cutting down the code to paste here.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, that was a remnant of me removing the other checks, good catch.  I'll update the code in the original post.

Comment: @YowE3K just checked and UsedRange is working correctly in giving me the correct rows.

Comment: I wonder whether it would actually be any slower to just run `For i = 3 To iusedRow` `colors = Split(colorMap(i, 1), ":")` `For j = 2 To UBound(colors) + 1` `If colors(j - 1) <> "" Then` `ds.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = CLng(colors(j - 1)` `End If` `Next j` `Next i`.

Comment: (Silly computer - my work firewall won't allow me to use chat.)  I just noticed that ds.Cells(i, j) should probably be ds.Cells(i, j-1).  (I think)

Comment: I just created 60,000 rows of data (using the 3 data rows in your OP and replicating the 3rd line an extra 59,997 times) and managed to colour all cells in about 4 seconds using code similar to my previous comment.

Comment: @YowE3K I think you were correct.  I needed to add in an extra parenthesis, however aside from that your solution is better in every way.  You've solved it.

Comment: Makes me wonder what the hell I was doing the first time I tried cell by cell.

Comment: Maybe you didn't have ScreenUpdating disabled when you first tried - without that disabled it would probably take several hours to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Dim ds As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim iUsedCol As Long, iUsedRow As Long, clrRequired As Long, color As Long

'...
'Set ds = .....
'...

iUsedRow = ds.UsedRange.Rows.Count

' Skip the first two rows
For i = 3 To iUsedRow
    colors = Split(ds.Cells(i, 1).Value, ":")

    ' Offset by one column since we're deleting column 1 after
    For j = 2 To UBound(colors) + 1
        If colors(j - 1) <> "" Then
            ds.Cells(i, j).Interior.color = CLng(colors(j - 1))
        End If
    Next j
Next i

' Delete the color map column
ds.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
```

That will process all colours in one loop.  (That may be a problem if you are only trying to set certain colours, as defined by your GetSetting calls.  If so, you may need to include an If statement to avoid processing if the colour specified isn't one of the colours you want to deal with.)

Comment: This is perfect, and finishes incredibly fast.  I feel like I tried something like this initially, but just completely missed the mark.  I think I over-complicated it with the color map garbage.  Thanks again.